# How do I keep transparency from one AI file to another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, background

I am trying to create a a shape for a project. As I started to create it, I realized that when I go to copy it into my other AI file, it has a white background to it and transfers over to my page as such. Here is the shape in the AI file by itself: [image: shape i am trying to create]

And then when I bring it into the file I want it in, it looks like this:
[image]

*(The graphic/bracket in the middle is the one I am trying to copy, and the one on the bottom is what I would like it to look like.)*

Any ideas why all the sudden my graphic is trying to create new shapes that I don't want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphic/bracket you're copying over has a white fill turned on whilst the bottom one has a transparent fill applied to the open path. It looks like a switch back to the default fill/stroke combo might have occurred in the file you're copying from.

Switching to a transparent [/] fill while the object is selected should correct that.